# Skipping rows with missing fields while loading a text file into a Spark Context

Tags: scala, apache-spark, csv

I need to load a tab delimited file into Spark Context. However some of the fields are missing values, and I need to filter out those rows. I am using the following code. However if the field is completely missing (e.g. one less tab in the row) this code throws an exception. What is a better way to achieve this?

```
val RDD = sc.textFile("file.txt").map(_.split("\t"))
.filter(_(0).nonEmpty)
.filter(_(1).nonEmpty)
.filter(_(2).nonEmpty)
.filter(_(3).nonEmpty)
.filter(_(4).nonEmpty)
.filter(_(5).nonEmpty)
```

Comment: I'd probably use a `flatMap` and  a `match`. That way you can even process the line in the same step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this to work nicely for large dataset:

```
val allRecords: RDD[Either[(String, String, String, String), Array[String]]] = sc.textFile(s"file.txt")
  .map(x=>x.split("\t"))
  .map {
     case Array(name, address, phone, country) => Left(name, address, phone, country)
     case badArray => Right(badArray)
  } 

val goodRecords = allRecords.collect{ case Left(r) => r }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read your file as a dataframe and use [DataFrameNaFunctions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions)

```
 val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter", "\t").load("file.txt")
 val cleanDF = df.na.drop()
```

[Here](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) is the link to Spark-csv library just in case.